# Sorting based on alphabets and then by numbers

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, typescript, sorting

I have to sort an array which contains dates and words. all the data is considered as string

```
INPUT
data[4,a,3,a,a,2]

OUTPUT(ascending expected)
data[a,a,a,2,3,4]
```

but when ascending, it sorts number first and then dates and vice versa. which is the opposite of what i wanted to achieve. How do i make it sort alphabets first while ascending and numbers first while descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if first character is a number.

If both are of comparisons are the same, compare regularly, else move the non-numeric first:

```js
var data = ["2020-04-07",
    "2021-06-30",
    "2019-12-30",
    "date passed",
    "date passed",
    "date passed"];
function specialSortAsc(a, b) {
    var isNumberRegEx = /^\d/;
    if (isNumberRegEx.test(a[0]) == isNumberRegEx.test(b[0])) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
    else {
        return isNumberRegEx.test(a[0]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
function specialSortDsc(a, b) {
    var isNumberRegEx = /^\d/;
    if (isNumberRegEx.test(a[0]) == isNumberRegEx.test(b[0])) {
        return b.localeCompare(a);
    }
    else {
        return isNumberRegEx.test(a[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
console.log(data.sort(specialSortAsc));
console.log(data.sort(specialSortDsc));
```

Comment: the datepassed should be below for descending

Comment: what was changed

Comment: In the `else` part of `specialSortDsc` i switched the return order.